# my thread in java is showing errors

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to android development. I have been trying to work this splashscreen with a audio file that kills itself after 3 secs. Then my Mainactivity is supposed to start. But my code is showing some error which i cannot figure out.the code n the java class is as follows:`

```
public class splash extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mySound;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    mySound=MediaPlayer.create(splash.this, R.raw.crowd_sound);
   mySound.start();
}
    Thread kill_Thread= new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                Intent splash_intent=new Intent(splash.this,MainLFC.class);
                startActivity(splash_intent);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    kill_Thread.start();


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mySound.release();
}
```

}

the manifest file is as follows:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainLFC"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.inten**strong text**t.action.MAINLFC" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: "But my code is showing some error" - what error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit the question to include the error. It may help you get more and better answers.

Comment: Do you even know java ? `kill_Thread.start();` ? outside of the method?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't start an activity from a non-UI thread.

Comment: @Selvin- like i said i am just learning. every tut i have seen seems to be like that. where should i use it then?

Comment: @Resueman-Error:(33, 34) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(37, 15) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(39, 9) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(40, 5) error: class, interface, or enum expected...all of these in the splash.java file

Comment: Dew, check my answer, can't be simpler, it's almost copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the behavior you pretend you must call your thread from within the onCreate method. For this you have two options, either keep using your thread and define it inside onCreate before calling it's start, or just use a Handler. Bellow theres your onCreate method for both options.

Using Thread.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    mySound=MediaPlayer.create(splash.this, R.raw.crowd_sound);
    mySound.start();
    Thread kill_Thread= new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                Intent splash_intent=new Intent(splash.this,MainLFC.class);
                startActivity(splash_intent);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    kill_Thread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mySound.release();
}
```

Using Handler

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    mySound=MediaPlayer.create(splash.this, R.raw.crowd_sound);
    mySound.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent splash_intent=new Intent(splash.this,MainLFC.class);
            startActivity(splash_intent);
            finish()
        }
     }, 3000);

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mySound.release();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response.

Comment: If it was helpful and solved your problem accept the answer as correct. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new activity should be done in the main (UI) thread.

If you want to communicate your thread with the main thread you can use a `Handler` and there start a new activity.

Example Handler:

```
Handler hander = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message m){
            Intent splash_intent=new Intent(splash.this,MainLFC.class);
            startActivity(splash_intent);
        }
    };
```

Example sending a msg to the handler:

```
Thread kill_Thread= new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                hander.sendMessage(Message.obtain());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    kill_Thread.start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.Only after seeing your code i started reading about handlers. So i thought let me just try the other code first. Still learning so.

Answer (score 0):

try this outside your on create method:

```
public class kill_Thread extends Thread{
 public void run(){
  try {
    sleep(3000);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Intent splash_intent=new Intent(splash.this,MainLFC.class);
             startActivity(splash_intent);
             }
          });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

where you declare your public variables set:

```
public kill_Thread kt;
```

and in your OnCreate call:

```
kt.start();
```

Comment: i tried this. still same errors. error in the */kill_Thread.start(); line. it can't recognise the start command or something.

Comment: I have updated my code. Try the new code